# Embedding a Google Chart with iframe

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, googlevis

So basically I am trying to either use the googleViz package and/or just embed a published google chart within a tabPaenl as an iframe and then have it automatically adjust to fit within the tabPanel embedded within the respective tabPanel in an R Shiny Web App. Any thoughts and/or suggestions would be awesome.

so I tried just using googleVis package and it stops the r-shiny app from loading because googleVis wants to open a graph in a separate webpage.

Basically I have a fluidRow that has to tabBoxes

```
                  fluidRow(
                    tabBox(
                      title = "Visualization Trends",
                      # The id lets us use input$tabset1 on the server to find the current tab
                      id = "tabset1", height = "500px",
                      tabPanel("First Response", 
                               "First Tab Content 1",
              I WANT TO EMBED THE CHART HERE
                               ),
                      tabPanel("Case Closure", "First Tab Content 2"),
                      tabPanel("SLA Met", "First Tab Content 3"),
                      tabPanel("SLA Missed", "Insert SLA Misses Content"),
                      tabPanel("Overall CR & MW", "Insert Google Chart")
```

The actual results have not been useful, and I am kind of stuck so I really just need some direction more than anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this wasn't as hard as I thought it would be.
In order to embed the chart you have to publish it first and then select the embed option. You then copy all of the content with

```
<iframe>some_embedded_content<iframe>
```

After you copy this you can then embed it within a tabBox Panel as such:

```
                      fluidRow(
                    tabBox(
                      title = "Visualization Trends",
                      # The id lets us use input$tabset1 on the server to find the current tab
                      id = "tabset1", height = "500px",
                      tabPanel("First Response",
                               HTML('<iframe width="600" height="371" seamless frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRNxLt1gp1TRc7sB83xjGpXLcLLUq8xH0B9iv1/pubchart?oid=1201606802&amp;format=interactive"></iframe>')

                               )
```

Comment: You get this from the embedding of the "HTML" component within the tabPanel.